# Adding constant error bars on pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, error-bars

I have seen many questions about error bars but is there a simple command that allows me to add, for example, a constant 5% or 0.1 error on all my points in the x/y direction. All the questions I have seen have complex commands for customizing the error on each which I do not want.

Thank you! (Sorry if this is a repeat)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I guess you will have a better chance to get the desired answer if you provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), or, at least a picture illustrating what you want. You can certainly change the symbol for the marks, if that's your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can do this. Here an example adapted from the PGFPlots manual with (fixed) relative x errors and fixed/constant y errors added to all plots of an `axis` environment.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        error bars/x dir=both,
        error bars/x fixed relative=0.5,
        error bars/y dir=both,
        error bars/y fixed=0.1,
    ]
        \addplot table {
            x   y
            0   0
            0.1 0.1
            0.2 0.2
            0.5 0.5
            1   1
        };
        \addplot+ [
            domain=0:1,
            samples=5,
        ] {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: How would I add it to just one plot?

Comment: Simply move all the `error bars/...` options to the `\addplot` options, i.e. `\addplot [error bars/...] ...`.

Comment: for some reason it gives me the error "i do not know the key to /pgfplots/table/error bars/y dir to which you passed 'both', ..." How do I fix this for tables?

Comment: nevermind, figured it out! You have to add another command box before table!